# Calculate remainder modulo with double exponent.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, self-learning, exponentiation

I recently stumbled upon this task:

$$ 10 * 2^{4+11^{85}} \equiv X \, mod \ 11 \\ Calculate \quad X$$

My approach was to split up and shorten the formula like this:

$$ 10*2^4  *    (10* 2^{11^{85}}) = 16* 10 * (10* 2^{11^{85}})  $$

Now I don't know how to calculate the double exponent without a calculator .

My question is: how do I quickly calculate X by hand with the double  exponent  ?

Comment: To solve the original task, maybe you should remember what 11 is (mod 11). Also some exponents can be treated easily with Fermats little theorem. However, this is not necessary here.

Comment: I cant follow you can you elaborate ?

Comment: is there a typo in the question? are you sure you want to compute $11(2^{4+11^{85}}) \equiv X \mod 11$ ? or do you want to compute $(2^{4+11^{85}} )\equiv X \mod 11$

Comment: @RoflUkulus do you mean $2^{11^{85}}  \equiv 0 mod 11 $

Comment: Look at the first factor of the left hand side. There is a 11. When you calculate in (mod 11). 11 is 0 (mod 11). A product is zero if one of the factors is zero :-)

Comment: sorry my bad, i have edited it. $10 * 2^4 \ldots$ is correct

Comment: @Arthur My bad, Arthur. Was typo

Comment: @RoflUkulus In any case, Fermat's little theorem is probably the way to go, as you said in your first comment. That (or Chinese remainder theorem + Euler's theorem in the worst cases) is my immediate response to any kind of large exponents in modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Fermat little theorem,

$$2^{10} \equiv 1 \mod 11$$

Let compute $$4+11^{85} \mod 10 \equiv 4+1 \mod 10 \equiv 5 \mod 10 $$

Hence the problem is equivalent to evaluate:

$$10 ( 2^5) \mod 11$$

You might like to note that $10 = 11-1$ and $32=33-1$.

Comment: I have read your answer but I dont understand the relevance of $2^{10} \equiv 1 mod 11 $ can you elaborate on that ?

Comment: By knowing that $2^{10} \equiv 1 \mod 11$, if you want to evalue $2^x \mod 11$ and you are able to express $x = 10k+r$,  then we have $2^x \equiv 2^{10k+r} \equiv 2^r (2^{10})^k \equiv 2^r \mod 11$. Hence we are able to simplify our working by working with $\mod 10$ in the exponent.

Comment: makes sense,  thanks for taking the time, answer accepted